# <ui:debug/> tag not working in Facelets (JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am doing a project using JSF 2.0 and Facelets.

I have read documentations that the `<ui:debug/>` tag gives valuable troubleshooting information upon pressing CTRL-SHIFT-D. But this never works for me. Please anyone tell me what am I missing.

(I tried with various hotkeys, still no success. eg: `<ui:debug hotkey="a"/>`)

Answer (score 31):

Ensure that you pick a key which isn't reserved by the webbrowser itself. In case of Firefox, a good choice is `x`.

```html
<ui:debug hotkey="x" />
```

#### See also:

- [how to debug JSF/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266953/how-to-debug-jsf-el)

---

Unrelated to the problem, I recommend to add a `rendered` attribute to ensure that it won't pop in a production environment. E.g.

```html
<ui:debug hotkey="x" rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}" />
```

in combination with this in `web.xml`

```html
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening in Firefox if I use the tag as:  <ui:debug hotkey="k"/> and then press CRTL+SHIFT+k when page is displayed. I am sure I am terribly missing something, but don't know what!

Comment: Maybe you have a too restrictive popup blocker.

Comment: Hang on, which context-param is the right one: facelets.DEVELOPMENT or javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT?

Comment: @Joshua: `facelets.XXX` are Facelets 1.x specific and `javax.faces.FACELETS_XXX` are Facelets 2.x specific (which became part of JSF 2.x). The `facelets.XXX` are deprecated in JSF 2.x, but still backwards compatible.

Comment: Okay, I'll switch to javax.faces.FACELETS_XXX since I'm using JSF 2.x.  I was trying to use this to figure out why I was getting this warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089076/the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't get it to work either until I placed the

```
<ui:debug hotkey="k" />
```

at the beginning of the TEMPLATE file, not the actual page. And I added the following to web.xml (but that was already mentioned):

```
<context-param>
    <description>
        Enables the ui:debug facelets tag.
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Sorry for the late answer, but I got it to work like this on Firefox 3. I don't think it's your popup blocker. The debug popup will usually get blocked, but you'll get a notification (as did I).

Comment: +1 for the point on the placement in the top template page. Also in my case it's working only if the tag is placed at the top-most level

Comment: +1 for the pointing the placement of <ui:debug hotkey="k" /> in the top template page. It Works!!!

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

Add the following to web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And add `<ui:debug hotkey="k"/>` to HTML part of template (not necessarily to the beginning)