# The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2

Here is my form:

```
<form action="j_security_check">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" bgcolor="#eff5fa" cellspacing="5" frame="box" styleClass="center">
        <h:outputLabel value="User ID:"/>
        <h:inputText id="j_username" tabindex="1" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Password:"/>
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password"/>
        <h:outputLabel value=""/>
        <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</form>
```

It work fine with Glassfish 3.0.1, but since Glassfish 3.1 b2 it shows this warning as a `FacesMessage` in the JSF page:

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within `<h:form>`

If I change the `<form action="j_security_check">` to `<h:form>`, it does not fix it, I have to place the `<h:form>` inside the `<h:panelGrid>`.

Comment: I'm still having this issue (with Glassfish 3.1-b37). Did you find a solution so far?

Comment: @Theo : I switch back to GF 3.0.1 as GF 3.1 gave me so much problem when I configure mail server. But as `@Carlo Pacheco` suggests `It only shows if you are in JSF Development based on your web config. javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE Development. When you change it to Production it wont show anymore`. I have not tried it, maybe you can verify what he said.

Comment: Behavior still present in 3.1.1.

Comment: This behaviour still exists in Wildfly 9.0.1.Final (which uses JSF 2.2, Mojarra implementation).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: **what** behaviour? Did you read all the answers? It is in many cases the right behaviour (if you made an error), so please be more specific in what exactly the problem still is, and if so, create your own new question referring this one.

Comment: @Kukeltje yes I did and I have understood the question. I am saying that, with the latest JSF implementation I am getting this warning, only in 1 particular case. I have to use the Development Project Stage during development so my code is written properly. I am just highlighting that this warning still exists, 4 years after this post was logged.

Comment: I get the warning to in cases where I made a mistake. If you still get it in a case you think you did not make a mistake, then please post in **which case**. Then it is helpful and maybe someone can create an issue with Mojarra (which version?)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is just a *Warning* not an *Error*. Warnings are usually there to inform the developer about unforeseen situations/conditions which might not immediately cause technical errors/problems. Anything may just work flawlessly, but the behaviour/results may probably not be as the developer intented. A newbie developer may for example accidently have used `<form>` instead of `<h:form>`. Warnings like this are then helpful.

In your particular case, you are simply forced to use `<form>` because of the need to submit to a non-JSF service. You as a more experienced developer know that it's legitimately valid. You can just ignore this warning. This warning will only appear when `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `Development` anyway and *not* appear when it is set to `Production`.

However, that it still displays the warning when there's another component like panelgrid in between the form and its input children, is a bug to me. I'd report it to the Mojarra guys. It look like as if it is checking the immediate parent only and not all of the parents. **Update**: it has been fixed as per Mojarra 2.1.3/2.2, see also [issue 2147](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2147).

This is by the way not Glassfish specific. The newer GF version of course ships with a newer Mojarra version which has those warnings implemented. See also [issue 1663](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1663).

#### Related questions:

- [The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741046/the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t)

Comment: There must be a way for now to shut down the warning. it must be something like setting the server log level to SEVERE instead.

Comment: if the warning is only inside the log, then I dont really mind, but it actually display onto the page, whether the page have p:growl, p:message or nothing at all.

Comment: Oh, it's displayed as facesmessage? This surprises me. Which JSF impl version is it?

Comment: Yeah it display as FacesMessages. Mine is Mojarra 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, it come with GF 3.1 b.25

Comment: That's a nightly/beta build... Right, Glassfish 3.1 itself is also beta.

Comment: There are nightly and promoted version. I use the promoted version. Here is the link http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/3.1/promoted/

Comment: Can we safely say that this is a bug and report that too Mojarra guys, BalusC?

Comment: I'm not sure. I quickly downloaded latest nightly of 2.1 from javaserverfaces.dev.java.net, added it to a Tomcat 6 playground environment with a copypaste of your form along with a `h:messages`. I didn't see a message, also not in the logs. Don't you have some special JSF debug settings in faces-config or web.xml I am not aware of?

Comment: I actually thought about that as well. I have another EE project that use the same security form as above, but it never gave me the FacesMessage. So i suspect something is wrong with me original project, but then I double check by deploy that original project onto GF 3.0.1, the FacesMessage go away. It kind of contradict my analysis. In my web.xml, nothing is out of the ordinary, `context-param`, `filter` for PF file upload and my custom filter, `servlet` for FacesServlet, and `security-constraint`. In faces-config, is just my navigation rule and managed bean

Comment: Maybe I have to take my words back and this is somehow GF 3.1 related. But still, this is plain weird. Google also [hints](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lamlXoidS1gJ:forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa%3FmessageID%3D485857+%22The+form+component+needs+to+have+a+UIForm+in+its+ancestry%22&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) that you're not the only one who encountered this on GF 3.1. One has mentioned that s/he already reported an issue, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Ahhh, now that we confirm that it a bug, I wont have to look anymore. Thank you BalusC

Comment: Yeah, I get this in GF 3.1 as well! The "workaround" is changing `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` from **Development** to **Production**. Hopefully, when JSF 2.1.1-b04 successor is stabled then this message will go away in Development mode. Like @BalusC said, it does confuse new developer - and they could spend hours frustrated by this issue. But experienced developers just ignore this as it's only a warning and doesn't show up when you change to Production mode.

Comment: FYI: I'm using JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final, which comes with "Mojarra 2.1.3 (SNAPSHOT 20110825)" and I do see this message on one of my pages.

Comment: I was able to figure out why this is still happening for me on Mojarra 2.1.3: I use a <c:forEach> to create tabs dynamically in a <rich:tabPanel>.   Apparently that hides the form from the <rich:tab>.

Comment: This thing is so annoying.

Comment: This issue is still present in Mojarra 2.2.15 (at least, a client id could be displayed to know which component is the cause...)

Answer (score 16):

This was suggested to me by Oleg from the PrimeFaces forum and works:

```
<h:form id="login" prependId="false"
                onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';">
```

Regards,
Brendan.

Comment: thanks Oleg and Brendan for helping to address this minor yet frequent annoyance.

Comment: Never use prependId="false". Search stackoverflow on why

Answer (score 4):

It only shows if you are in JSF Development based on your web config.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

When you change it to Production it wont show anymore

Comment: Guys, did the javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE set to Production help you? Unfortunatelly for me this value is never set for some reasons, I checked it by `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getProjectStage()`
and it always returns Development!

Comment: Change the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to **Production** work.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone will find this usefull one day,
i had same error and the problem was that i have primefaces component

```
<p:something ....
```

and that component was not inside `<h:form>` element

Comment: Nice idea. The warning/error message went away when I enclosed my `<p:commandLink...` in `<o:form>` extends the standard `<h:form>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.27 and find out that this is my mistakes. However its just very hard to find what the mistakes was. Hopefully someone from Mojarra could add component id to the warning messages.
Here is what I did to found out the component: (which also posted to https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1586#c48)

I trace it by downloading the Mojarra source code and adding break point to com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl class in method:
public void addMessage(String clientId, FacesMessage message).
when the break point catch, open the Debugging window or call stack window to find out that it was called by class
com.sun.faces.application.view.FormOmittedChecker 
in method
private static void addFormOmittedMessage(FacesContext context)
which is previously called by method

public static void check(FacesContext context).

inside the check method there is parameter variable component.
You can get the component id from Watch or variable window and then trace it back to your html page and code.

Its a hard way, but hope you can find the root of the problems. It will be much more simpler if the warning message also display the problematic component id

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer to the question, or just long, helpful comment.

Comment: I've created an issue for them https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4026?filter=-2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this warning message was displayed in `p:messages` which I've put in dialog to show validation errors, so I've just included `severity="error"`in `p:messages` and warning message was gone.

Comment: That is sort of just hiding like setting the log level to error to hide the warning messages. It is not a real 'solution'.