# The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I am getting the following error on my Facelet page, which simply consists of an IceFaces form with two fields and two buttons:

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>

Here is the form:

```
<ice:form id="form1" partialSubmit="false">
    <ice:panelLayout id="panelLayout3">
        <ice:graphicImage id="graphicImage1" url="/resources/images/LoginImage.jpg" width="560" />
        <ice:outputLabel for="j_username" id="outputLabel1" value="Username:"/>
        <ice:outputLabel for="j_password" id="outputLabel2" value="Password:"/>
        <ice:inputText binding="#{login.username}" id="j_username" required="true" />
        <ice:inputSecret binding="#{login.password}" id="j_password" required="true" />
        <ice:commandButton  actionListener="#{login.login}" id="loginBtn" value="Login"/>
        <ice:commandButton action="#{login.reset}" id="resetBtn" value="Reset"/>
        <ice:outputText id="errorMessage" />
        <ice:message errorClass="errorMessage" for="j_username" fatalClass="fatalMessage" id="messages1" infoClass="infoMessage" showSummary="false" warnClass="warnMessage"/>
    </ice:panelLayout>
</ice:form>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not an error. This is a warning. The code looks fine, all input components are inside a form, it seems that it should run and work fine. If it indeed works fine, just ignore the warning. This warning is displayed only when the context parameter `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `Development` anyway .

As to the false warning message itself, this check was introduced in Mojarra 2.1.1 as per [issue 1663](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1663). However, as per [issue 2147](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2147) it turns out to have some bugs and is been further improved in Mojarra 2.1.3. I'd imagine that the false warning is in your particular case caused by having an `<ice:panelLayout>` between the form and the input elements.

If you aren't on Mojarra 2.1.3 yet, you may want to consider upgrading to see if it removes the false warning message.

Comment: i am using JSF 2 Mojarra (api from javax.faces & impl from com.sun.faces: `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>`

Comment: FYI: I'm using JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final, which comes with "Mojarra 2.1.3 (SNAPSHOT 20110825)" and I do see this message on one of my pages.

Comment: @BalusC Is there any way to prevent those from being displayed as face messages while staying on development stage ? Because I've those messages all over my pages and it's annoying to design with this useless message.