# How to handle a part of a form components where loaded by AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf

I have a form like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText/>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <!-- AJAX content will come here containing h:inputText elements -->
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText/>
</h:form>
```

Now using AJAX I put content into the panelGroup - and this content also contains h:inputText elements.. if I don't have a form tag in the included content I will get a warning - and if I have a form then I will have nested forms

What I would like is to have the content injected using AJAX to be part of the form already present - is that possible?

Comment: To be clear, your sole concern is the false development stage warning? The form itself works just perfectly fine? Are you using an outdated Mojarra version and you haven't tried upgrading to latest just to exclude an already long fixed bug from being the cause? In any case, even though you did nowhere copypaste the exact warning, this is likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741046/the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t

Comment: To be honest  I actually didn't try code - I stopped when I got the warning. I will try to run the code, and see whether it works.