# How to disable development stage messages?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I like to know if it is posible disable the error messages that appear at the bottom of the page when I have some JSF syntax error:

```
<ul title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages" 
   id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages">
  <li style="Color: orange">    
    The button/link/text component needs to have a Form in its ancestry. Please 
    add <h:form>.
  </li>
</ul>
```

And you can't say "add the form tag".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the `<context-param>` with name of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` from your `web.xml`, or set its value to `Production` instead of `Development`.

#### See also:

- [The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089076/the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t)