# JSF commandButton - passing POST params to an external site

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need a link which redirect me to a different site and send POST parameters. Something like:

```
  <h:form> 
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="http://example.com"> 
      <f:param name="user" value="robson"> 
    </h:commandButton> 
  </h:form>
```

The code above doesn't work of course.

I'd like to acheive this in HTML:

```
  <form action="http://example.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="robson">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @BalusC - as you could see in my other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232209/facescontext-redirect-with-post-parameters) - the problem now is form in form. I learned that plain HTML is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the vanilla HTML `<form>` tag, not the JSF  tag if you're going to send form data to a non-JSF target.

The [JSF form tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/form.html) is designed to facilitate [JSF postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) operations, which is why it has no "action" attribute.

Comment: Can I use jsf components inside `<form>` or just HTML ones?

Comment: Should work. You might face [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089076/the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t](the-form-component-needs-to-have-a-uiform-in-its-ancestry-suggestion-enclose-t)

Comment: I have problem yet with `<form>` in `<h:form>` - and I have to manage with it, but it indeed works, thank you

Comment: You are welcome ... If you are facing some other problem, please raise it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do this :(