# <p:growl> causes "The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry"

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162018/5829191) answer it is as below possible to eliminate that popup while developing mode enabled.

```
<h:form id="f1" prependId="false" onsubmit="document.getElementById('f1').action='j_security_check';">                      
    ...
</h:form>
```

But it's not working for me when I add `<p:growl>`

```
<h:form id="f1" prependId="false" onsubmit="document.getElementById('f1').action='j_security_check';">                      
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

How can I solve it?

My config: Wildfly 8, Mojara 2.2.x (server runtime), PrimeFaces 5.3

Comment: Is the popup you are referring to the "The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>" pop-up described in the linked question?

I don't see any tags in your excerpt that *should* be causing that message; they are all wrapped in `h:form`. Are there any other components on the page not included in your excerpt?

Comment: @Chatoyancy the above snippet does not contain any other components except those you see in the question. and that warning message disapears if comment `p:growl` component

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following solved the problem:

```
<p:menubar id="pmenubar">
    <p:menuitem value="Inicio" url="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/hola.xhtml"
                    icon="ui-icon-home" />
</p:menubar>
```

I forgot to close this component. As you might have noticed, the component has neither `actionListener` nor `action`, so you need to enclose it in a form:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menubar id="pmenubar">
        <p:menuitem value="Inicio" url="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/productos/crear-producto.xhtml"
                    icon="ui-icon-home" />
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```