# Is Facelets page generated to Servlet as JSP generated to Servlet

Tags: jsf, compilation, facelets

As all JSPs are generated / translated to Servlets before their execution, is its true for Facelets too?

I am working with JSF 2.0 and Facelets and wanted to see its generated Java Code which might be Servlet.

Answer (score 13):

No, Facelets files are parsed to a XML tree using a [SAX parser](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/compiler/SAXCompiler.java#SAXCompiler). The XML tree is stored in the [Facelet cache](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/impl/DefaultFaceletCache.java#DefaultFaceletCache). The XML tree is during [view build time](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/view/FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java#FaceletViewHandlingStrategy) turned into an [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) tree which is accessible by [`FacesContext#getViewRoot()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29) (which you can traverse by `getChildren()` during runtime). The component tree normally generates HTML code by their own `encodeXxx()` methods or the ones on the associated [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html), starting with [`UIViewRoot#encodeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeAll%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29).

Facelets files **do not** generate any class files. The XML trees are by default stored in server's memory. Since JSF 2.1 you can however specify a custom [`FaceletCache`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletCache.html) implementation by `<facelet-cache-factory>` in `faces-config.xml` wherein you can write code to store the XML tree on for example the disk file system (which would be slower, though).

If you use `<ui:debug>` in the view and open it, then you can see the textual representation of the component tree behind `UIViewRoot`. See also [how to debug JSF/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266953/how-to-debug-jsf-el/8269559#8269559/)

#### See also:

- [Why not JSF pages are precompiled (atleast partially) but instead parsed, evaluated each time view is built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894035/why-not-jsf-pages-are-precompiled-atleast-partially-but-instead-parsed-evalua/)
- [What's the view build time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time)
- [Measure the render time of a JSF view after a server request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106118/measure-the-render-time-of-a-jsf-view-after-a-server-request/)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o/)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same way, it gets cached. But it doesn't generate servlet code.

Comment: Can you please, tell me the java code for this xhtml tag <f:verbatim escape="false"> <br /> </f:verbatim>