# Measure the render time of a JSF view after a server request

Tags: jsf-2, rendering, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I would like to measure the rendering time of a JSF application. Because of out of my power reasons, the application can't be populated with logs.

Therefore, my question would be, is there any way in which I can measure the rendering time of the application after doing a certain action that includes a back-end(server) call using any browser?

So far,after using the Chrome Developer Tools,I spotted the following. On the Network tab, each request has the "Time" displayed. In addition, after selecting a certain entry, on the "Timing" tab, a more detailed visualization it's displayed.
Now, I can tell from that that the "Waiting" that the round-trip to the server it's captured here, but what about the actual rendering time.

Assuming that the whole request took 1sec, and the Waiting section it's 500ms, can I deduct that the rendering it's the 1sec-500ms ? I assume not, thats why I am asking this question.

Long story short, I would need to know from the browser, for a certain request how long was the server processing and how long was the actual UI rendering.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with a custom [`ViewDeclarationLanguage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html) whereby you measure the [`createView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#createView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-), [`buildView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#buildView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot-), [`renderView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#renderView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot-) and if necessary [`restoreView()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#restoreView-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-) methods.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class VdlLogger extends ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VdlLoggerFactory.class.getName());

    private ViewDeclarationLanguage wrapped;

    public VdlLogger(ViewDeclarationLanguage wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot createView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        UIViewRoot view = super.createView(context, viewId);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info(String.format("create %s: %.6fms", viewId, (end - start) / 1e6));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void buildView(FacesContext context, UIViewRoot view) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        super.buildView(context, view);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info(String.format("build %s: %.6fms", view.getViewId(), (end - start) / 1e6));
    }

    @Override
    public void renderView(FacesContext context, UIViewRoot view) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        super.renderView(context, view);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info(String.format("render %s: %.6fms", view.getViewId(), (end - start) / 1e6));
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDeclarationLanguage getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

To get it to run, create the below factory:

```
public class VdlLoggerFactory extends ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory {

    private ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory wrapped;

    public VdlLoggerFactory(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDeclarationLanguage getViewDeclarationLanguage(String viewId) {
        return new VdlLogger(wrapped.getViewDeclarationLanguage(viewId));
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

And register it as below in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<factory>
    <view-declaration-language-factory>com.example.VdlLoggerFactory</view-declaration-language-factory>
</factory>
```

The `createView()` is the step of creating the concrete `UIViewRoot` instance based on `<f:view>` and `<f:metadata>` present in the view files. When using Facelets (XHTML) as view, during this step all associated XHTML files will be parsed by the SAX parser and cached for a time as defined in `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD`. So it may happen that it's one time relatively slow and the other time blazing fast.

The `buildView()` is the step of populating the JSF component tree (the `getChildren()` of `UIViewRoot`) based on the view (XHTML) composition. During this step, all taghandlers (JSTL and friends) are executed and all EL expressions in those taghandlers and component's `id` and `binding` attributes are evaluated (for detail, see also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)). So if backing beans are constructed for first time during view build time and invoking business logic during `@PostConstruct`, then it may happen that this is time consuming.

The `renderView()` is the step of generating the HTML output based on JSF component tree and the model, starting with `UIViewRoot#encodeAll()`. So if backing beans are constructed for first time during view render time and invoking business logic during `@PostConstruct`, then it may happen that this is time consuming.

If backing beans are incorrectly performing business logic in getter methods instead of in `@PostConstruct` or any other one-time-occurring life cycle event listener, then it may happen that this consumes yet more time. See also [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times).

Comment: That's just... awesome. Thank you!

Comment: [ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.html) was added in 2.2. Do you think it would be easy to modify this to work with 2.1 or would I be better off looking for another way to implement it?

Comment: @SamHasler: Extend `ViewDeclarationLanguage` instead, of (IDE-)generate a `ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper` yourself. [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.0/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java/?v=source) is not rocket science ;)