# p:ajax taking a lot of time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using empty `p:ajax` in `p:selectOneMenu` and the time taken to send the request and the first response from server is approximately 1.02 secs. Why is It taking this much time. 1 sec. for empty ajax call is too much.
Following is my code :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id = "myId"
                 value = "#{myBean.myAttr}"
                 styleClass = "myClass"
                 disabled = "#{myBean.isDisalbed}">
    <p:ajax />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Attached is the image of the time consumed on changing a value in drop down.

Network Response on option change.

[image]

Comment: Bad network? Old PF version (not that it would make a difference, it always worked for me) Do some network sniffing

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33106118

Comment: @BalusC, that is really helpful to analyse it further. But if you look at the code below my ajax statement looks like this :  `<p:ajax  onstart="PF('ajaxCurtain').block;" complete="PF('ajaxCurtain').unblock" update="myId myAnotherId"`  Total time it takes from blocking the screen to unblocking the screen is approx. 6 secs. but the code you had given shows : 3ms in create, 55ms in build and 710ms in render phase. not sure where rest of the time is going.

Comment: @Kukeltje, i am using PF 5.3 version.

Comment: Check your network (do some sniffing) check if you have bad server side security filters, check if there is a bad firewall or proxy check if the block() is slow, check…

Comment: 710ms render response time is quite a lot for an ajax request which basically renders nothing. Perhaps you've request scoped beans tied to the view doing fairly expensive stuff during construction? At least, hints to that were already given in the link. As to the 6 secs, you didn't include that information in the question?