# JSF : Huge difference of time between render phase and loading of screen

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

I have used the solution given in [Measure the render time of a JSF view after a server request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106118/measure-the-render-time-of-a-jsf-view-after-a-server-request), to override the phases of primefaces and when my **render phase ends**, `System.currentTimeMillis()` shows value `1454506208193` and in my javascript file `new Date.getTime()` on `jQuery(document).ready` gives value `1454506233981` **the difference is almost 25 secs**. I just want to know, are there any other phases between render phase and elements appearing on UI, that might be taking this much of my time.

Edit : Attaching image :
[NETWORK IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ItI.png)

Comment: Nothing in the JSF side at least. Remains are just HTTP server, HTTP connection, HTTP client and HTML parser (and all hardware/software related to it). For example, Microsoft Internet Explorer 6-8 trying to digest a 10-column HTML table with 1000 rows may take that long on a 10 year old laptop. I'd start running a HTML/JS profiler in client side to exclude HTTP server and connection from being the probable cause.

Comment: Did you try using a stopwatch? Is it realy 25 seconds or is there a time difference between client and server ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje, I tried using stop watch as well, it takes approx. 31 secs to load the page. I am running the application on localhost, so there is no time difference between client and server. i have tried running profiler on my JS, my JS takes like 1 sec. I am getting the same time on IE11 as well and I am really not sure what and how to proceed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Debug network traffic? Drop the 56k modem? You are the only one that can investigate the part between the render end server side and the start of rendering client side

Comment: And btw, how is this PrimeFaces related? Post an [mcve] and try replacing PF components with their plain jsf counterpart if possible to exclude PrimeFaces

Comment: You are right, it should be JSF. @Kukeltje

Comment: @BalusC, i have attached an image and it shows that it is downloading or trying to download lots of resources and that is taking time.

Comment: @Kukeltje, Really sorry i wont be able to share the code. but i have attached an image of my network on page load.

Comment: Looks like a LOT of network latency…  AND a lot of different resources…  sounds to me that it is totally not jsf related