# Performance impact of using too many EL expressions in JSF

Tags: performance, jsf, richfaces, el

Our hosted JSF web application (built with Richfaces 4.4 + Spring + Mybatis) currently is facing an issue of slower response times on a specific page. Part of the problem is a slower broadband connection being used by the client. But one of the other issue is that the page relies heavily on multiple EL expressions (7-8 for a `required` or `rendered` condition inside the `rich:` or `h:` element )for displaying a set of grid like input elements that the user is supposed to fill out. I was wondering if this could be the primary issue. The average data transferred for loading this page varies from 1000-1600 kb. The no. of database queries were also a problem but those have been optimized now to around 1 sec. However on 4mbps connection, this page loads in 5-8 secs, far slower than the others which load in 2-3 secs.
Any guidance on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to break down and profile those 5-8 secs. For instance, your question isn't at all clear in whether that time took place in server or client side. If e.g. JSF is done in 1 sec and the particular webbrowser needs 6-7 secs to build the HTML DOM based on JSF-generated HTML output, then you know where to continue your focus. Here's at least a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33106118

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I'll look into the related question and provide more details.