# Running non get/set managed bean class function

Tags: jsf

I'm really new to JSF, and I'm trying to understand something yet I failed doing so using the oracle documentation,

Let's say I have this class as a managed bean

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Test {


    public void Trying()
    {

        System.out.println("Testing");
    }

}
```

how can I call the Trying() function from within my html view page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">


    <h:body>


            <b style="font-family:arial;font-size:15px"> #{---CALL FUNCTION---}</b>



    </h:body>

</html>
```

Also, when using JSF which part calls the "Model" part of the MVC architecture? 
the view or the controller?, and how is that implemented behind the scenes? when is my java code compiled?

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and see resources. There you will find tutorials and books. Read. A lot.

Comment: Please ask one question per Question. It'll be easier to find answers (and duplicates). Your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5104094 Your third question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3541077 Your fourth question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13173633