# Is there any relation b/w Restore View Phase and caching a Facelet?

Tags: caching, facelets, jsf-2.2

The caption says it all.
By default, JSF performs periodic checks of Facelets views changes
And the check can be configured through context parameter

```
javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD
```

Further, there is this method in abstract class `FaceletCache`

`public abstract boolean isFaceletCached(URL url);`

which can be overridden to cache `Facelet` or not.

I was looking at the default implementation of `FaceletCache` but couldn't get to know whether Facelets are cached by default or not.

```
/**
 * Default FaceletCache implementation.
 */

final class DefaultFaceletCache extends FaceletCache<DefaultFacelet> {
    @Override
    public boolean isFaceletCached(URL url) {
        com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull("url", url);

        return _faceletCache.containsKey(url);
    }


     //.....
}
```

And when should one really cache Facelet?

Comment: Is this related question helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13173633

Comment: @BalusC: Indeed that helps/helped. Thanks.