# How to open <ui:debug> with Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, jsf-2, facelets, hotkeys

I try to debug JSF on Mac (10.10.1) and Chrome (39.0.2171.95) with `<ui:debug />`, but on Mac all combinations I tried have no effect, even if I tried to change to `<ui:debug hotkey="ö" />` which should [normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266953/how-to-debug-jsf-el/) work on Windows with Ctrl+Shift+ö.

This is what I've tried:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd>

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd>

All without success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd>.

The command does not adhere to the mac standard of <kbd>⌘ (COMMAND)</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but rather goes for the windows approach of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>