# Is it possible to debug for duplicate Ids?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm getting a duplicate id error but I can't figure out which element is meant.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: duplicate Id for a component pb_1_WAR_TEST_INSTANCE_1234_:_viewRoot:mainForm:tableOverview:j_id66
```

I know it has to be in tableOverview but the element with the ID:
`j_id66` can not be found. When I search for it in my browser, I can only find elements with higher Id's like,

```
pb_1_WAR_TEST_INSTANCE_1234_:_viewRoot:mainForm:tableOverview:j_id67
```

Is there any way to find out which one is meant?

Comment: It's likely a column component. As to the problem, are you using `binding` attribute to bind a component to a bean which is not in the request scope? That's one of most common mistakes causing this problem.

Comment: @BalusC ok, I kicked out all binding tag's and replaced them. I understand that binding is evil in session scope as you have written here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14917453/5146922) But is there a way to debug this automaticaly created id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a `<h:column>` or `<rich:column>`.

Quick way to find out the exact component is `findComponent()`:

```
UIComponent component = context.getViewRoot().findComponent("pb_1_WAR_TEST_INSTANCE_1234_:_viewRoot:mainForm:tableOverview:j_id66");
System.out.println(component); // HtmlColumn?
```

Alternatively, just print out the JSF component tree. JSF 2.x offers [`<ui:debug>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266953/how-to-debug-jsf-el) for this, in JSF 1.x you have to write custom code which traverses and prints `UIViewRoot` and all its children recursively. Here's a kickoff example:

```
public static void print(UIComponent component) {
    System.out.println(component.getId() + " = " + component.getClass());
    for (UIComponent child : component.getChildren()) {
        print(child);
    }
}
```

```
print(context.getViewRoot());
```

As to your concrete problem, it's most likely caused by binding a component to a bean which is not in the request scope. Don't do that.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158)
- [Binding attribute causes duplicate component ID found in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101755)