# Breakpoints not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I've got a JSF Application with ManagedBeans and I'm trying to debug the code inside my ManagedBeans with breakpoints (eclipse Java EE mars).

As stated in the answer to this question here: [How to debug JSF/El](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266953/how-to-debug-jsf-el) it should be as easy as add a breakpoint inside a method of a ManagedBean and get the method executed and eclipse will stop when the breakpoint is reached, right?

Now if I add a breakpoint in eclipse (rightclick -> "Toggle Breakpoint") my program just runs through as if there was no breakpoint.

Did I get forget some basic thing or did I get the concept of debugging in JSF wrong or is this most likely a bug / misconfiguration or any other thing?

Comment: Well, since it workes for me in 'Mars' and worked in all previous eclipse releases without any configuration and I never had to 'configure' anything, I'm sure it is neither a bug nor a misconfiguration. But are you sure you are running the appserver/servletengine from within Eclipse in debugging mode or run it as remote debugging?

Comment: Ah here we go. Needed to start the server in debug mode. Thanks! Please add as an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: Take a pick which counts as a duplicate and I will mark it as such   https://www.google.nl/search?q=stackoverflow+debug+webapp

Comment: Well, search in google in general... SOOOOO much info that no-one needs to ask questions like this. And your question is so specific, title wise, that others may skip it reading. It is e.g. totally not jsf related but general java webapp debugging.