# Catch the problematic line in JSF-page-debugging?

Tags: debugging, jsf, exception, facelets

I get an exception of

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/consult_carto.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Now I can't solve it yet, so I thought I might debug the JSF page and I went on to find that the `<ui:debug />` helps with that, tried it just to find that it doesn't give much information.

My **Question** is : is it possible to know which line throws the exeption in a JSF page ? If so, how do we do that ?

Thanks.

**Links** : used this one :  [tag not working in Facelets (JSF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049531/uidebug-tag-not-working-in-facelets-jsf-2-0) (and it works fine).

Comment: Just look in Java renderer source code at the lines mentioned in the stack trace? If you can't decipher it, just ask a question with the full stack trace.

Comment: That's what I do usually, but just wanted to know if there's a way to debug line by line a JSF page. Is there ?

Comment: Only if the bug is in XHTML code, not in Java code. JSF will then by default show line and char number of the problem in XHTML. In your particular case, the bug is apparently in Java code. Then you just have to read the source code indicated in the stack trace the usual way.

Comment: Ok. Just to know it's possible good. Seems my issues is with java as you say, thanks.

Comment: As example, try removing a quote from a tag attribute like `value=#{bean.value}"`. You'll see a XHTML parsing error.

Comment: Yes it does, but these are just syntaxe errors, what about exceptions specific to JSF rendering ?

Comment: That's already explained in my previous comments. Just look at source code the usual way based on stack trace.

Comment: Ok got it, so always have to dive in java code. Thanks !

Comment: I now see that you're the same person who asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014942/commandbuttons-actionlistener-fire-a-java-lang-illegalargumentexception. I've already posted an answer over there related to this problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I seperated the questions I thought this is a more general question that deserves it's own discussion.