# selectItems java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I really have given this quite some time before posting it, but I just don't seem to narrow down to the source of the trouble.

I have this "basically" simple code, let's just say that once I click on a `<p:commandButton>`, an action is fired that fills an ArrayList which is to be invoked on a `<p:dataTable>`.

My `<p:commandButton>` is :

```
<p:commandButton value="Afficher" actionListener="#{fieldController.fillListFields()}" ajax="false"/>
```

as for my my `<p:dataTable>`, it's like this :

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{fieldController.listFields}" id="carList" editable="true">
```

The `#{fieldController.listFields}` is an ArrayList that the `#{fieldController.fillListFields()}` must take care of filling. The code for `fillListFields()` is :

```
public void fillListFields() throws NamingException, SQLException {

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("postgresJNDI");
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + consultCarto.getForm());


        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            listFields.add(new Field(rsmd.getColumnName(i), ""));
        }

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        connection.close();

    }
```

Now I have debugged this method and the ArrayList `listFields` is well filled, that much I can assure you. 
Problem is once I deploy the app and click on the `<p:commandButton>` I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, I have no idea which component on the JSF page is not receiving proper argument (btw I know it's in the JSF page because I get

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/consult_carto.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

)

I checked the setters and getters, and they look ok.

Any indications on where I should look ?

The stack :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditorRenderer.encodeEnd(CellEditorRenderer.java:43)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:808)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:773)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:651)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:234)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:196)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:82)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thanks.
```

The essential part of my markup :

```
<h:form id="form" style="font-size: 13px;">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                    Consulter les données cartographiques 
                </f:facet>
                <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
                        <p:outputPanel> 
                            <h:outputText value="Choisir un formulaire : " /> 
                            <br></br> 
                            <br></br> 
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{consultCarto.form}" >  
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{consultCarto.forms}" />  
                            </p:selectOneMenu> 
                        </p:outputPanel> 
                        <p:commandButton value="Afficher" actionListener="#{fieldController.fillListFields()}" ajax="false"/>                        
                    </p:panelGrid> 
                    <!--  start of filter panel -->
                    <div id="filter_datatable" >
                        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{fieldController.listFields}" id="carList" editable="true">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Requête 
                            </f:facet>

                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{fieldController.onEdit(event)}" />
                            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{fieldController.onCancel(event)}" />

                            <p:column style="width:6%">
                            </p:column>


                            <p:column headerText="Champ" style="width:24%">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{car.field}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.field}" >
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{car.field}"
                                                           var="man" 
                                                           itemLabel="#{man}"
                                                           itemValue="#{man}" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Valeur" style="width:20%">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{car.value}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{car.value}" style="width:100%" label="pseudo"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="width:6%">
                                <p:rowEditor />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                        <p:commandButton value="Filtrer"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of filter panel -->
                </p:panelGrid>
                <iframe name="iframe" src="carto.jsp" height="500" width="950" id="iframe"></iframe>
            </p:panelGrid> 
        </h:form>
```

Comment: You should provide the full stack trace.

Comment: also provide the consult_carto.xhtml markup

Comment: Added those, quite long stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is just in the stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298)
```

The `MenuRenderer` is been used in `<h:selectOneMenu>`. The `SelectItemsIterator` is been used in `<f:selectItems>`. It's helpful to just look at line 216 of [`SelectItemsIterator`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/SelectItemsIterator.java#185) as identified in the stack trace:

```
203            if (value != null) {
204                if (value instanceof SelectItem) {
205                    updateSingeItemIterator((SelectItem) value);
206                    items = singleItemIterator;
207                } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
208                    items = new ArrayIterator(ctx, (UISelectItems) kid, value);
209                } else if (value instanceof Iterable) {
210                    items = new IterableItemIterator(ctx,
211                                                     (UISelectItems) kid,
212                                                     (Iterable<?>) value);
213                } else if (value instanceof Map) {
214                    items = new MapIterator((Map) value);
215                } else {
216                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
217                }
218            }
```

It's thus caused by the `<f:selectItems value>` not being an instance of `SelectItem`, or array, or `Iterable` or `Map`, but being completely different and illegal/unsupported type.

Fix the `<h:selectOneMenu>` usage accordingly based on [our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

Comment: Indeed, took me a while to grasp it, but I think it was the `<f:selectItems>` taking `#{car.field}` which is neither a `SelectItem` nor an `Iterable` or `Map`.

Comment: I'll change the title of the thread to "selectItems java.lang.IllegalArgumentException", which I think is closer to describe it for futur searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like from

`<h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.field}" >
     <f:selectItems value="#{car.field}"
                                     var="man" 
                                     itemLabel="#{man}"
                                     itemValue="#{man}" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>`

can you check 'car.field' value. And you remove ajax=false.

Comment: Was correct about `#{car.field}`, but not about taking away `ajax=false` (would be interested to know why you suggested taking it off though).

Comment: You right, ajax false not about error. It is only about performance on web. There is detailed answer for this. http://www.coderanch.com/t/581862/JSF/java/happen-ajax-true-ajax-false

Comment: Nice ! Thanks for the link !

Comment: That link with `process="@form"` did fix another (other) IAE: "Unrecongnized content type" triggered by a `p:commandButton` you need to add that attribute with exact same value to that tag. Any reason why does it fix it? `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Content Type. at  com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:283)` is the message.