# JSF: Print all request parameters via EL

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, el

I want to create a simple Eclipse template showing me all current page parameters and its values.

First approach would be something like:

```
        <c:forEach var="pname" items="$<PARAM_NAMES>">
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                    <h:outputText value="${param}" />
                </td>  
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="${param.pname}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to build this is invalid because it is included out of the box.

```
<ui:debug hotkey="x" rendered="#{initParam['javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE'] == 'Development'}" />
```

Tips to get started with ui:debug:

[<ui:debug/> tag not working in Facelets (JSF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049531/uidebug-tag-not-working-in-facelets-jsf-2-0)

This assumes JSF 2.0. If you are not on JSF 2.0 why not just create it in a bean with `ExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()`?

Comment: nice way to do handle this via bean. Thanks a lot!